# Where does pip install packages?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

When I run `pip list` it tells me Pygame is installed, and I can import it:

[image: my command prompt]

But when I view the folder that is supposed to hold the installed packages, Pygame is not there:

[image: the file with the imported modules viewed in windows explorer]

(Note the other modules appear in the file, as expected) A search for 'pygame' in C:\Python27 turns up nothing.

Where is Pygame installed?

Comment: Do try to avoid screenshots. Console output should be text formatted as a code block. You can just tell us the path you checked where you think pygame should be, or post the result of a `dir` command.

Comment: You might also notice that numpy is missing. Show the results of running `where python`, as text, by editing your question.

Answer (score 5):

`pip show pygame` should give you the right indication under `"Location"`.